# Pygame: столкновение

Tags: python, pygame

Я начал изучать библиотеку PyGame и задача такова: нужно сделать так, чтобы игрок (прямоугольник) падал вниз, пока не столкнётся с каким-либо спрайтом (платформой в моём случае). ЛКМ - создаёт платформу, ПКМ - перемещает игрока по координатам мыши. Так же клавишами "право" и "лево" игрок сдвигается на 10 единиц в право/лево соответственно.

Почему у меня не падает игрок вниз, ведь условие выполняется, а само действие в классе PlayerBorder не выполняется.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
size = width, height = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
back_color = pygame.Color('black')
running = True
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
######
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
things = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(things)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, group):
        # НЕОБХОДИМО вызвать конструктор родительского класса Sprite. Это очень важно!!!
        super().__init__(group)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.add(group)

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, 20, 20))


class Barriers(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, group):
        # НЕОБХОДИМО вызвать конструктор родительского класса Sprite. Это очень важно!!!
        super().__init__(group)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.add(group)

    def update(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('grey'), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height))


class PlayerBorder(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, group):
        super().__init__(group)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.add(group)

    def update(self):
        if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, things):
            self.rect.y += 50 / fps
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('white'), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height))
#####


def move(key):

    if key == 'left':
        player.rect.x -= 10
        l_b.rect.x -= 10
        r_b.rect.x -= 10
        u_b.rect.x -= 10
        d_b.rect.x -= 10
    elif key == 'right':
        player.rect.x += 10
        l_b.rect.x += 10
        r_b.rect.x += 10
        u_b.rect.x += 10
        d_b.rect.x += 10

player = Player(20, 20, all_sprites)
l_b = PlayerBorder(player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y - 1, 1, player.rect.y + 2, all_sprites)
r_b = PlayerBorder(player.rect.x + 20, player.rect.y - 1, 1, player.rect.y + 2, all_sprites)
u_b = PlayerBorder(player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y - 1, 22, 1, all_sprites)
d_b = PlayerBorder(player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y + 20, 22, 1, all_sprites)
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    things.update()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    player.render()
    all_sprites.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                Barriers(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], 50, 10, things)
            elif event.button == 3:
                player.x, player.y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
                d_b.x, d_b.y = player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y + 20
                u_b.x, u_b.y = player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y - 1
                r_b.x, r_b.y = player.rect.x + 20, player.rect.y - 1
                l_b.x, l_b.y = player.rect.x - 1, player.rect.y - 1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move('left')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move('right')
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: А self.rect.y случайно не типа int? А то тогда будет прибавляться int(50/60) = 0, то есть ничего не будет прибавляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я проверил, **self.rect.y** у вас точно имеет тип **int**, когда вы к нему прибавляете int(50/60), то есть ноль, то ничего, естественно, не происходит. Если задать **fps** поменьше (например, **25**), то на экране что-то начинает происходить.